# Cannot Install Ubuntu Server 16.04.6

Tags: system-installation

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu Server 16.04.6.iso and turn in into and convert it using Rufus. I set my usb to be the first in the boot order. I get to the install menu, when I press the option install ubuntu, it pauses then the screen says no signal and restarts back to the menu.

By the way I am using old hardware that was using windows vista, I have not uninstalled windows vista because I believe when ubuntu is installed it will remove windows vista. I am using a Gateway E-6610D SB

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a hunch, it could be an issue with Rufus. I've not had the best of luck with it myself. For the last year or two, I've been using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) without much hastle.

It could also be that the installation media Rufus spits out is UEFI and not compatable with the older BIOS system you are using, or visa versa.